# SIGSEGV does not terminate the process

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have a multithreaded application that runs 30-something threads. I know there is a bug where sometimes two threads attempt to sort one list simultaneously and this usually results in one of the threads accessing invalid memory. Thus, a `SIGSEGV` is generated for that thread.

Now, from what I understand about signals, the thread should call `SIG_DFL` for `SIGSEGV`, which is abnormal termination of the process and a coredump. However, I saw the process being still alive (in a kind of limbo state) where the execution halted, but the process was still alive. When I tried to `kill` it, the `SIGTERM` was actually propagated to my custom signal handler (which attempts to nicely shut down all the threads), but there it hang up, because none of the threads were actually executing anymore. I finally managed to kill it using `SIGQUIT` and the corefile was generated after that.

So my question is what is meant by "abnormal termination"? How can a process not be removed from the memory if the `SIG_DFL` is called for `SIGSEGV`? What could possible be going on that caused such behaviour? My Linux is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)

EDIT: I know (more or less) how to debug it and I even know what the bug is. My question is more or less: What exactly RedHat does when SIG_DFL is called with SIGSEGV? The problem here is that the process was not responding, but was not dead either - therefore the automatic restart procedure did not kick in and we had some unpleasant downtime.

Comment: You say you have a custom signal hander, what does it do?

Comment: The expected behavior of SIGTERM is to terminate a process, but it's possible to catch SIGTERM and do something else. SIGKILL is the uncatchable force quit. i.e. `kill -9 12345`

Comment: Also, by any chance did `ps` list your process as <defunct> ? If so, it was a zombie process (i.e. it quit but its return value was not read by the starting process yet).

Comment: Did you pstack it? This should be the first thing to do.

Comment: @ADAM The custom handler notifies the other threads to release DB connections they could be holding. I will try 'ps' next time.

Comment: @SergeyA I did not pstack it, next time I will have a look. I have only a coredump where I can see stacks when the Segmentation fault occurred.

Comment: Unless you've altered the default behaviour the process should abort on SEGV. I think you need to show us what you have done that may get you into this behaviour. At first thought I'd guess that you have installed a handler for `SIGSEGV` too which would alter the default behaviour.

Comment: Classic XY problem. What you should be solving is the attempt to sort the same data from two different threads.

Comment: @EJP Hello, I agree that will remove the problem, but that is not what I am asking. The next time I receive a SIGSEGV from a different bug, I want to make sure the process really is aborted and that didn't happen here.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're catching the SIGSEGV signal? If you are, try just not catching that signal at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation was not as straightforward as I thought. The original problem was a deadlock between two of the threads. When I issued SIGTERM, then actually my custom signal handler caused a segfault in the (now un-)deadlocked threads.